# Normalization problem

Tags: normalization

Let's suppose a database table such as this:

**Table = {Competition, Sport, Game, Player, Score}**

And we have these functional dependencies:

**Competition + Game + Player -> Score**

**Game -> Sport**

**Player -> Sport**

So for the table, the primary key: Competition+Game+Player. Let's apply second normal form with the second dependency above. The result is:

**Scores = {Competition, Game, Player, Score}**

**Games = {Game, Sport}** (primary key: Game)

But we have missed the information about the sport that each player practices.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You also need Players {Player*,Sport} (*=key). As you can see, 2NF isn't very useful. What matters is that all your FDs are implied by superkeys, which is what BCNF and 5NF are about.